# Problem: Squares of a Sorted Array | Can anyone lookout this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, optimization

Can anyone recorrect this code?
Code is not working properly.
The output should be a square sorted array. 
Example :Input: [-4,-1,0,3,10]
Output: [0,1,9,16,100]
I'm using Leetcode platform.

```
class Solution(object):
    def sortedSquares(self, nums: List[int]):
        out = []
        for num in nums:
            out.append(num**2)
        self.sorte(out)      

    def sorte(self, out):
        if len(out)<2:
            return out
        else:
            return self.sorte([each for each in out[1:] if each < out[0]]) + [out[0]] + self.sorte([each for each in out[1:] if each >= out[0]])
```

Comment: Could you explicitly define your problem?

Comment: Could you state what you expect the output to be and what it actually outputs?

Comment: Small suggestion - break up that super oneliner into a few lines. Maybe even add a comment. You'll do yourself and others working with you a favor building habits of writing very clear and readable code

Comment: Yes, I did and re-edited the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted solution:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, A: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        out = [x*x for x in A]
        return sorted(out)
```

If you still want to do like yours check if this can help:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, A: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        out = []
        for num in A:
            out.append(num**2)
        return self.sorte(out)      

    def sorte(self, out):
        if len(out)<2:
            return out
        else:
            return self.sorte([each for each in out[1:] if each < out[0]]) + [out[0]] + self.sorte([each for each in out[1:] if each >= out[0]])
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm using Leet code platform and somehow I'm getting error like 'function is not defined / Runtime error'.

Comment: I have added the accepted piece of code. Please check. Your code will give "Time Limit Exceeded" .

Comment: yes, actually. For same right now I'm thinking about it, that how should I pass all test-cases by re-editing and optimize the code. Can you suggest me out on the same problem?

Comment: In your sorte method, instead of using recursion for sorting which is increasing its time complexity, can't you use any existing algo to sort which takes nlogn? Python's inbuilt sort algorithmn is TimSort. Its time complexity is nLogn .

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timsort/ -> Check this to learn more about TimSort .

Comment: I got that but not completely. As I'm a beginner in competitive programming and did solve this problem using Quick Sort method. Still, I'm confused with the same problem.

Comment: As a beginner, I should stick with the neat clean concept and code implementation techniques, instead of using built-in functions.

Comment: Yes sure, then you can write a algo which is having complexity of nLogn. Because you earlier code was going somewhat beyond n^2 .

Comment: Yes sure, thank you.